# Fluent nHibernate - not Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, lazy-loading

It's probably something silly but I can get my head around it. I have three tables

```
Post
id
content
...
User 
id
name
...
Vote
user_id
post_id
votedate
```

My VoteMap:

```
public class VoteMap : ClassMap<Vote>
{
    public VoteMap()
    {
        DynamicUpdate();

        Table("vote");            
        Id(Reveal.Member<Vote>("_id")).Column("id");
        Map(Reveal.Member<Vote>("_votedate")).Column("vote_date");

        References(x => x.Post).Column("post_id").LazyLoad().Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.User).Column("user_id").LazyLoad().Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

PostMap:

```
public class PostMap : ClassMap<Post>
{
    public PostMap()
    {
        DynamicUpdate();

        Table("post");
        Id(Reveal.Member<Post>("_id")).Column("id");
        Map(Reveal.Member<Post>("_content")).Column("content");
        References(x => x.User).Column("user_id").Not.Nullable().LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

UserMap

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        DynamicUpdate();

        Table("user");
        Id(Reveal.Member<User>("_id")).Column("id");
        Map(Reveal.Member<User>("_name")).Column("name");

        HasMany(x => x.Posts).KeyColumn("user_id").LazyLoad();
        HasMany(x => x.Votes).KeyColumn("user_id").LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

When I retrieve Vote:

```
var myvote = _votesRepository.GetVote(postid, userid);
int post_id = myvote.Post.Id;
int user_id = myvote.User.Id;
```

**Vote** attributes are set correctly. **Post** and **User** references are of type **Castle.Proxies.PostProxy** and **Castle.Proxies.UserProxy** and their attributes are empty. 
(**post_id** and **user_id** are set to 0)

Shouldn't nHibernate lazy load this data?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you map the private fields (`"_id"`) for Id, and not the `Id` properties ? Though I'm really not familiar with private fields mappings, I wonder if it would fit well with lazy loading, especially for identifiers. Have you tried replacing these with property mappings ?

Comment: Because all my entities have read-only properties (not allowing an entity to be in an invalid state).  I replaced private attributes with public virtual properties as suggested but still I get the same result. It only works when I obviously add .Not.LazyLoad() to all mappings.

Comment: Having relevant code of your entity classes would help understanding your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right jbl, it doesn't like private id fields at all. This change solved the problem:

```
protected int _id;
public virtual int Id { get {return _id;} }
```

and changing my mapping for all classes from this:

```
Id(Reveal.Member<Vote>("_id")).Column("id");
```

to this:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("id");
```